# Unity application to simulate a foveal field of view - but how?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For research purposes, I would like to create a Unity VR 3D application that (more or less) simulates the foveal field of view of a person. This means, in particular, I would like to render the whole environment of the application in the full field of view, but certain objects of interest I only want to render in the foveal area.

[image]

For the purpose of explaining the problem, I created a simple 2D picture. Please assume it's 3D. In the picture, the green area is the peripheral field of view, and the yellow area is the foveal field of view. The whole environment, like walls, sky, etc., should get rendered in the green and in the yellow area. Particular objects of interests, here the flowers, however, should only get rendered only in the yellow area and - importand - these objects should get cut off when reaching the green area. With this approach, I want to force people moving their head instead of just moving the eyes.

Any idea how to achieve this? Is it possible to use a kind of mask or filter? Or do I need a stencil shader? I looked around but could not find the correct approach.

Comment: I have never done anything like this but maybe you could render two layered camera's with different properties on a Canvas and mask/move the top layer to your needs.

Comment: That's an approach I also thought about but how to deal with stereo rendering...?